# Python list append multiple elements

Tags: python, list

I want to append multiple elements to my list at once. I tried this

```
>>> l = []
>>> l.append('a')
>>> l
['a']
>>> l.append('b').append('c')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
   l.append('b').append('c')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
>>>
```

how can I append `'b'` and `'c'` at once?

Comment: `my_list + ['a','b']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `append()` works **in place**. In other words, it modifies the list, and doesn't return a new one.

So, if `l.append('b')` doesn't return anything (in fact it returns `None`), you *can't* do:

```
l.append('b').append('c')
```

because it will be equivalent to

```
None.append('c')
```

**Answering** the question: *how can I append 'b' and 'c' at once?*

You can use `extend()` in the following way:

```
l.extend(('b', 'c'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`list.extend`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
>>> l = []
>>> l.extend(('a', 'b'))
>>> l
['a', 'b']
```

Note that similar to `list.append`, `list.extend` also modifies the list in-place and returns `None`,  so it is not possible to chain these method calls.

But when it comes to string, their methods return a new string. So, we can chain methods call on them:

```
>>> s = 'foobar'
>>> s.replace('o', '^').replace('a', '*').upper()
'F^^B*R'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l = []
l.extend([1,2,3,4,5])
```

There is a method for your purpose.

Comment: oops, another person gave the same answer at the almost same time.